# Keyboard layout on login

Tags: debian, login, keyboard-layout, xkb

Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), no GUI

Recently something happened to my SSH, so I need to login to my debian locally. I stuck on login (GUIless) because of keyboard layout, which by default is likely set to "ru" and has no hotkey to switch. I've tried them all...
I've also tried to mount sd card on another computer and edited '/etc/default/keyboard' to

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

No luck either. Nothing changed. Layout is still 'ru' and hotkey doesn't work.
So, how to switch layout to english to be able to login?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem: (man keyboard) "In the following configuration the right <Alt> key (grp:toggle) will toggle between US QWERTY layout  (us)  and  Greek  (gr)  layout.  ** The  option
       grp_led:scroll is ignored on the console** but in X in means to use the ScrollLock keyboard led as indicator for the current layout (US or Greek)."